# Avoiding overfitting in LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have written code using Keras and TensorFlow to recognize a pattern in a cyclic dataset. The thing which I worried about was overfitting and how to avoid from being overfitted. Now, from the loss value and accuracy, it seems I have become overfitted. The code is below:

```
#importing libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.layers import InputLayer

# Reading dataset
df = pd.read_excel("concate35w270.xlsx")
df = df.astype('float32')
df.head()


scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range= (0,1))
df = scaler.fit_transform(df)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

#Looking last time step

def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY
# Reshaping dataset
# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 1
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

look_back = 1
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)


# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))




# Network Architecture 

# create and fit the LSTM network
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu))
#model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))



def coeff_determination(y_true, y_pred):
    SS_res =  K.sum(K.square( y_true-y_pred ))
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square( y_true - K.mean(y_true) ) )
    return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot + K.epsilon()) )

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', 
         loss='mse',
         metrics = [coeff_determination])



model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs = 30)
```

After starting to fit model using the training data set, I saw this massages from the machine:

```
Epoch 1/30
702543/702543 [==============================] - 64s 91us/sample - loss: 0.0376 - coeff_determination: 0.4673
Epoch 2/30
702543/702543 [==============================] - 61s 86us/sample - loss: 0.0015 - coeff_determination: 0.9791
Epoch 3/30
702543/702543 [==============================] - 60s 86us/sample - loss: 0.0014 - coeff_determination: 0.9802
Epoch 4/30
702543/702543 [==============================] - 64s 91us/sample - loss: 0.0013 - coeff_determination: 0.9812
Epoch 5/30
702543/702543 [==============================] - 68s 97us/sample - loss: 0.0013 - coeff_determination: 0.9820
Epoch 6/30
702543/702543 [==============================] - 67s 96us/sample - loss: 0.0012 - coeff_determination: 0.9827
Epoch 7/30
702543/702543 [==============================] - 67s 95us/sample - loss: 0.0012 - coeff_determination: 0.9834
```

I guess I should define a penalty to avoid from overfitting, How can I do that?
All help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think this article would help in general : https://towardsdatascience.com/handling-overfitting-in-deep-learning-models-c760ee047c6e

Comment: @ShivamMohan thanks for the comment, I needed to know, is it good to write my own code from the scratch while there a lot of libraries with a powerful API that can do the same things? I did not want to write since I thought it reinventing wheel needlessly. Could you please give me your IDEA?

Comment: Sorry but your question makes no sense, the only way to check for overfitting is to use validation data, and you are not providing this. You cannot infer overfitting just with training data or with the training loss.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I did not get your point. If you mean the code which I mentioned above does not provide information about being overfitted or not because of just putting training data, you're right I have to go more forward to become sure. But, I would like to know it's good to write my own code or using prepared libraries?

Comment: That seems to be a different question than the one in your question, please put the question and all the details in your post.

Answer (score 2):

Your **test** data meant to be for monitoring the model's overfitting on train data, so you have to insert `validation_data` parameter in your `.fit` method like this:

```
model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY), epochs=30)
```

Detailed information you can get in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60035755/how-do-i-know-if-my-neural-network-model-is-overfitting-or-not-keras/60035875#60035875).